# No spacing between the tab names in shiny applications

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have created a shiny application and there is no extra spacing between the tabs which I have rendered to the UI. I am using bs4dash shiny framework for the UI. Is this issue related to the this framework?

[image]

```
code :

tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                          tabPanel(title = "abc", 

                                   rHandsontableOutput("contentsl"),tags$style(type="text/css", "#contentsl th {font-weight:bold;}")),
                          tabPanel(title = "fgh",
                                   rHandsontableOutput("content1"),tags$style(type="text/css", "#content1 th {font-weight:bold;}")),
                          tabPanel(title = "hjk",
                                   rHandsontableOutput("content2"),tags$style(type="text/css", "#content2 th {font-weight:bold;}")),
                          tabPanel(title="pqr",rHandsontableOutput("prem"),tags$style(type="text/css", "#prem th {font-weight:bold;}")),
                          tabPanel(title="Scatter Plot View",plotlyOutput("pl9",width = "100%",height = "600px")),
                          tabPanel(title = "Box Plot View",plotlyOutput("pl8",width = "100%",height = "600px")),
                          tabPanel(title = "Plot Data",rHandsontableOutput("pl.data",width = "100%",height = "100%"),tags$style(type="text/css","#pl.data th {font-weight:bold;}"))
                          ))
```

Comment: you should add a fully reproducible code (i.e. a code that includes the packages used and the ```ui``` and ```server``` parts), especially because you use bs4dash

Comment: I have tried a workaround which is not a good way to fix this issue is by adding spaces before and after the title name in the tab panel.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me if I implement it in a basic Shiny app (automatically created). Here's the code (this is not really an answer but it can't fit in a comment so if it is useless I will remove it):

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(plotly)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(
                type = "tabs",
                tabPanel(
                    title = "abc",

                    rHandsontableOutput("contentsl"),
                    tags$style(type = "text/css", "#contentsl th {font-weight:bold;}")
                ),
                tabPanel(
                    title = "fgh",
                    rHandsontableOutput("content1"),
                    tags$style(type = "text/css", "#content1 th {font-weight:bold;}")
                ),
                tabPanel(
                    title = "hjk",
                    rHandsontableOutput("content2"),
                    tags$style(type = "text/css", "#content2 th {font-weight:bold;}")
                ),
                tabPanel(
                    title = "pqr",
                    rHandsontableOutput("prem"),
                    tags$style(type = "text/css", "#prem th {font-weight:bold;}")
                ),
                tabPanel(title = "Scatter Plot View", plotlyOutput(
                    "pl9", width = "100%", height = "600px"
                )),
                tabPanel(title = "Box Plot View", plotlyOutput(
                    "pl8", width = "100%", height = "600px"
                )),
                tabPanel(
                    title = "Plot Data",
                    rHandsontableOutput("pl.data", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
                    tags$style(type = "text/css", "#pl.data th {font-weight:bold;}")
                )
            )
        )
        )
    )


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I have no idea what it is, but surely you should mention it in your post. Did you try the code in my post? If yes, does it work or do I need to remove my answer?

Comment: well my advice is that you put a fully reproducible code in your post and not only a part of it, that will make it easier for people to help you